# How to add external google_play_service library in my project? (other than own sdk's)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-play-services

I have an android project from bitbucket with its own google play
service library. When i add that library to my project `eclipse` is
giving me an error on `@integer/google_play_service_version`. But
if i am adding my own sdk's lib into the project i am not able to see
the correct output (eg. unable to load maps, etc).

So can anyone please help me?? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey guys, I have solved this problem by reinstalling the google play service from SDK manager! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, add in manifest:

```
  <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="4242000" />
```

Comment: Hey, but i read somewhere that it is not safe bcoz when we update the google play service then every time we have to add its version!

Comment: But when you update your google play service every time you have to change your version number so the best way to use like this:<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: Ok. But i it shows error on android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version".

Comment: check your version number from your Google_Play_services Library and add it as integer : " google_play_services_version " to the Values.xml file . @Anmol Nimbalkar

Answer (score 0):

Add Google play service from adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject.

Don't forgot to mention these meta data in manifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

then clean and build your project and run it again.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: i did all the things on stackOver. but thing is that i want to add externl google library which i downloaded from bitbucket with the source code!

Comment: I think you are using updated Google play service wich is not matched with your sdk version so you have to update it accordingly but what is the problem with your own sdk google play service.

Comment: the project that i have imported from bitbucket contains its own google_play_service_lib.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link from Android Developer site;

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

If it is from bitbucket,
1. Unzip your file
2. Import to tour workspace by Click File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace
3. Add Reference library to your project (http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) 
4. Add

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

this inside your application element of the Manifest file